# is my code wrong or is my computer slow?

Tags: c

I'm coding in c and have been attempting to make an average calculator, as i am new to coding and only just starting and my code won't work after i input a number for it. the way it should work is you input a number, the code keeps track of the overall number and the amount of numbers entered and prints out the average, doing this all in "do while" loop

my code:

```
int main()
{
float overall = 0;
float entered = 0;
float times = 0;
float avg = 0;

printf("AVERAGE CALULATOR\n\npress 0 when complete\n\n");
do{
    printf("current average: %.2f\n\n", avg);
    printf("input number: ");
    scanf("%f", entered);
    overall += entered;
    times++;
    avg = overall / times;

}while(entered != 0);

        return 0;
}
```

pleae inform me of incorrect code if you find it

Comment: `scanf("%f", entered);` => `scanf("%f", &entered);`

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: You should clarify what you've tried so far, and not just use Stack Overflow as a place to say "please fix my code".  If you put effort into your question, others will put effort into answers.

Comment: If you are manually entering numbers to be averaged, the speed of your computer is going to be completely irrelevant, even if you spend years entering numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the (**&**) in **scanf** after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

scanf("%f", &entered);
Scanf needs a pointer to your adress.